# var in console command C#

Tags: c#

How can I insert a var in console command? i mean somthing like that:

```
string color = Console.readline();
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.color;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to have to convert the string to a ConsoleColor.  Like this:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var colorName = Console.ReadLine();
        try {
            ConsoleColor color = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), colorName, true);
            if (color == Console.BackgroundColor) throw new ArgumentException("That would make invisible output");
            Console.ForegroundColor = color;
            Console.WriteLine("Okay");
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Not the greatest solution, the French won't understand why "Blanc" doesn't work.

Comment: Enum.Parse() throws an ArgumentException if the input value isn't part of the enumeration. Whence comes the FormatException?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this:

```
string color = Console.ReadLine();
Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor) Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), color);
```